# (C Programming) Making a char ** array like argv

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In a program I am writing I made a Tokenize struct that says:

```
TokenizerT *Tokenize(TokenizerT *str) {

    TokenizerT *tok;
    *tok->array = malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT));
    char * arr = malloc(sizeof(50));
    const char *s = str->input_strng;
    int i = 0;

    char *ds = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(ds, s);

    *tok->array[i] = strtok(ds, " ");

    while(*tok->array[i]) {
        *tok->array[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    free(ds);
    return tok;
}
```

where TokenizeT is defined as:

```
struct TokenizerT_ {
    char * input_strng;
    int count;
    char **array[];
};
```

So what I am trying to do is create smaller tokens out of a large token that I already created. I had issues returning an array so I made array part of the TokenizerT struct so I can access it by doing tok->array. I am getting no errors when I build the program, but when I try to print the tokens I get issues.

```
TokenizerT *ans;
TokenizerT *a = Tokenize(tkstr);
char ** ab = a->array;
ans = TKCreate(ab[0]);
printf("%s", ans->input_strng);
```

TKCreate works because I use it to print argv but when i try to print ab it does not work. I figured it would be like argv so work as well. If someone can help me it would be greatl appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you don't allocate for `tok` and `tok->array`

Comment: We a more complete example to help you.

Comment: I'm curious what you believe `char * arr = malloc(sizeof(50));` does. I suspect you meant `malloc(50)`; as it happens, `sizeof(50)`, `sizeof(42)` and `sizeof(32767)` all evaluate to the same number (4 on my system, but it can be different). `sizeof` is not part of the magic of `malloc`; it is a compile-time expression which produces the size in bytes required for a type, where the type is either named or, as in your code, represented by an (unevaluated) expression that type. So `50` is standing in for the type `int`.

Comment: I know this is what you meant but still,.. it is `char * array`, or a `char **`.. if you are trying make something like the  `argv` that is  normally used in `main( )`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Creating the Tokenizer

I'm going to go out on a limb, and guess that the intent of:

```
TokenizerT *tok;
*tok->array = malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT));
char * arr = malloc(sizeof(50));
```

was to dynamically allocate a single `TokenizerT` with the capacity to contain 49 strings and a NULL endmarker. `arr` is not used anywhere in the code, and `tok` is never given a value; it seems to make more sense if the values are each shifted one statement up, and corrected:

```
// Note: I use 'sizeof *tok' instead of naming the type because that's
//       my style; it allows me to easily change the type of the variable
//       being assigned to. I leave out the parentheses because
//       that makes sure that I don't provide a type.
//       Not everyone likes this convention, but it has worked pretty
//       well for me over the years. If you prefer, you could just as
//       well use sizeof(TokenizerT).
TokenizerT *tok = malloc(sizeof *tok);
// (See the third section of the answer for why this is not *tok->array)
tok->array = malloc(50 * sizeof *tok->array);
```

(`tok->array` is not a great name. I would have used `tok->argv` since you are apparently trying to produce an **arg**ument **v**ector, and that's the conventional name for one. In that case, `tok->count` would probably be `tok->argc`, but I don't know what your intention for that member is since you never use it.)

#### Filling in the argument vector

`strtok` will overwrite (some) bytes in the character string it is given, so it is entirely correct to create a copy (here `ds`), and your code to do so is correct. But note that all of the pointers returned by `strtok` are pointers to character *in the copy*. So when you call `free(ds)`, you free the storage occupied by all of those tokens, which means that your new freshly-created `TokenizerT`, which you are just about to return to an unsuspecting caller, is full of dangling pointers. So that will never do; you need to avoid freeing those strings until the argument vector is no longer needed.

But that leads to another problem: how will the string be freed? You don't save the value of `ds`, and it is possible that the first token returned by `strtok` does not start at the beginning of `ds`. (That will happen if the first character in the string is a space character.) And if you don't have a pointer to the *very beginning* of the allocated storage, you cannot free the storage.

#### The TokenizerT struct

`char` is a character (usually a byte). `char*` is a pointer to a character, which is usually (but not necessarily) a pointer to the beginning of a NUL-terminated string. `char**` is a pointer to a *character pointer*, which is usually (but not necessarily) the first character pointer in an array of character pointers.

So what is `char** array[]`? (Note the trailing `[]`). "Obviously", it's an array of unspecified length of `char**`. Because the length of the array is not specified, it is an "incomplete type". Using an incomplete array type as the last element in a `struct` is allowed by modern C, but it requires you to know what you're doing. If you use `sizeof(TokenizerT)`, you'll end up with the size of the struct *without* the incomplete type; that is, as though the size of the array had been 0 (although that's technically illegal).

At any rate, that wasn't what you wanted. What you wanted was a simple `char**`, which is the type of an argument vector. (It's *not* the same as `char*[]` but both of those pointers can be indexed by an integer `i` to return the i<sup>th</sup> string in the vector, so it's probably good enough.)

---

That's not *all* that's wrong with this code, but it's a good start at fixing it. Good luck.